# Who explains Aharon not deviating in this way?

Tags: commentaries, lighting, bamidbar-numbers-book-of, menorah--in-temple, aharon

In the beginning of Be'haaloscha, Rashi explains that Aharon lit the menorah in the same fashion each time. Which meforash elaborates on this pshat, explaining that he did it with the same vigor throughout his life and never viewed it as a monotonous task?

Comment: Isn’t that the simple reading of rashi?

Comment: @Chatzkel I don't think so

Answer (score 2):

The [שפת אמת (תרל"ה](https://he.m.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%A4%D7%AA_%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%AA/%D7%91%D7%94%D7%A2%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%AA%D7%9A)) explains this thought.

He writes that when it comes to a repetitive Mitzva, it is human nature to be passionate about doing it at first, but as time goes on, this passion is forgotten. Not so Aharon Hakohen, his passion stayed the same every day.

Additionally, being that the first passion is the best, he was able to acquire higher levels of spirituality with each kindling.

Answer (score 1):

I have also heard this idea in the name of the Sefas Emes ([1847-1905](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yehudah_Aryeh_Leib_Alter)). In my search for this idea, I stumbled upon the *sefer* Siach Sarfei Kodesh, a collection of chassidish insights by [this scholar](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A2%D7%A5_%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A7%D7%93%D7%99%D7%A9_%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A7%D7%90%D7%A5).

In [volume 5, p. 21b *s.v.* שמעתי](https://tablet.otzar.org/#/book/108671/p/40/t/3553762761234/fs/0/start/0/end/0/c), it quotes this idea from the **Kotzker Rebbe** ([1787-1859](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menachem_Mendel_of_Kotzk)), who in turn brings if from the Yehudi HaKadosh, **Rav Yaakov Yitzchok of Peshischa** ([1766-1813](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yaakov_Yitzchak_of_Peshischa)).

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: If you found this useful, feel free to upvote and mark as correct.